# Deployment box is not opening in deployment mode for Drools Business Central

Tags: java, jbpm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9wF5.jpg)Deployment Box is not coming in deployment mode to deploy project in drools business central. It only came once but now  its not coming

I tried restarting the server and bounce business central but nothing worked for me. So please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.